# Making sense of Julia's do-blocks with functions

Tags: julia

Looking at the `get` function of base Julia, it is [apparently](http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/function/get) intended to be used using a do-block:

```
  get(dict, key) do
      # default value calculated here
      time()
  end
```

The signature for `get` is `get(Dictionary_name, Key_name, Default Value)`. This means that the do-block automatically inserts the default value as the last argument of `get`.

When I compare this syntax for the do-block with the one in [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-does-this-do-syntax-mean/25041/3) thread, I notice a difference:

```
my_function(f, container) = begin
    for element in container
        f(element)
    end
    return nothing
end

my_function([1,2,3]) do x  # equivlent to my_function(print, [1,2,3])
    print(x)
end
```

Notice how the function `f` is the very first argument of `my_function`, so the do-block inserts `print` as the first argument of `my_function`, not the last.

This is my confusion: Why is it that the do-block in one example inserts the variable as the last argument, but in another inserts in as the first?

Comment: @Giovanni's answer is right, but I think it's burying the lede: `do` *always* passes its result as the *first* argument to the function before `do`.  Consult [the docs for `do` here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments) to see the explanation.

Comment: Also, if you look in the `get` docs just above that part you quoted, you'll see that the signature you were talking about is `get(f::Function, collection, key)`.  It's that `f` that `do` is passing in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` has several methods, you can check the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Methods) to know what methods are, which you can list with `methods(get)`.
If you run `methods(get, (Function, Dict, Any))` which would be the method called with the do block you show, you should see something like

```
# 1 method for generic function "get":
[1] get(default::Union{Function, Type}, h::Dict{K, V}, key) where {K, V} in Base at dict.jl:528
```

if instead you call `methods(get, (Dict, Any, Any))` you get the method you were referring to.

If in the REPL you try to type

```
d = Dict("a"=>1, "b"=>2)
f(x) = time()
?get(f, d, "a")
# the '?' should enter the help?> mode but doesn't work if this is copy pasted
```

you should see the help message for the method of `get` that gets called in the case that you show with the do block which is equivalent to this one. So the do block is inserting the function as a first argument and this makes it call another method.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The called `get` function is not the one you thought.

In such cases, if you have any doubt, you can use the `@which` or `@less` macros :

```
julia> dict=Dict()
Dict{Any, Any}()

julia> key="A"
"A"

julia> @which get(dict, key) do
           # default value calculated here
           time()
       end
```

which prints :

```
get(default::Union{Function, Type}, h::Dict{K, V}, key) where {K, V} in Base at dict.jl:528
```

The `@which` macro gives you the prototype of the called `get` function and where it is defined (here dict.jl line 528).

If you want to have a look at the source, use the `@less` macro:

```
julia> @less get(dict, key) do
           # default value calculated here
           time()
       end
```

which prints :

```
function get(default::Callable, h::Dict{K,V}, key) where V where K
    index = ht_keyindex(h, key)
    @inbounds return (index < 0) ? default() : h.vals[index]::V
end
```